# How to change style of scroll-bar with a fixed position in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I tried using two different angular plugins that both used directives to create the scroll bar. My problem is that the scroll bar that I want to change is on a vertical navbar and that navbar is in fixed position.

So when I place the directive in the navbar it builds the new scroll bar fine, how ever the old default scroll bar is still there, this is because the navbar has a max height and a `y-overflow = auto` if i change it to `y-overflow = hidden` then the new scroll bar wont go all the way down to the bottom of the navbar.

I know there is a css solution but its not compatible in most browsers so I need to do this in javascript.

So my question is can any one help me alter the scroll bar on a fixed element without the default scroll bar being there and allowing the new scroll bar to go all the way to the bottom of the navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution I can give you (if I understood) you can hide the scrollbar you don't need

There is a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in Webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari).  That rule is:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

There is a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in IE 10+.  That rule is:

```
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

There used to be a CSS rule that could hide scrollbars in Firefox, but it
 has since been deprecated.  That rule was:

```
.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

Would be fine if you put the plugins you were using. Or the code you were using to try. Or any kind of reference: Plunker, JSBin, JSFiddle, etc